# git how to do first commit after creating a repository

Tags: git

I work with git. I created a directory reflections4 and I copied a file in it. After this, I executed git init.

```
git log displays 

carlotavina (master #) reflections4 $ git log
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet

git status

carlotavina (master #) reflections4 $ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    lesson_1_reflections.txt 

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

How can I display Initial commit in git status after creating a repository

Comment: As the message suggests, use `git add <file>` to include it in what will be committed, then make a commit.

Comment: `git add lesson_1_reflections.txt && git commit -m'initial commit'`

Comment: As `git status` says, there are no commits yet. You've created a new, totally-empty repository. The first commit you make will become the first commit ever, in that repository. (Then the *second* commit will refer back to the first one, and the third to the second, and so on.)

Answer (score 0):

You have not yet committed anything to the repository, only initialized one. From the documentation, linked below, init creates an empty repository, and does no population. Some services (github/lab, etc) will initialize the repository with a readme file or similar, which must be committed to be tracked. Manually running init does not do this.

You must add (commit) something to the empty repo it to see it. As such, if you `git add lesson_1_reflections.txt` and `git commit -m "first commit"`, you will than have a commit that you are able to look at.

If you are trying to sync with a remote repository (one hosted on another server, github, gitlab, bitbucket, etc.), there are additional steps you will have to take to make the two repositories (local and remote) talk to each other.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

```
git add lesson_1_reflections.txt
```

Step 2:

```
git commit -m "<enter the desired commit message>"
```

Step 3 (after you set up a remote to push into):

```
git push
```

If prompted enter user and password

Answer (score 0):

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/basic-git-commands-776639767.html
Lookout on this webpage you will find every information you want.

In your case, you have to add those files to your repository by

`git add . // . means everything or "all"`

```
git status // now you can see all the changes
git commit -m "Message that you want to send regarding this commit"
git push origin "whatever the branch name"(optional)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have empty repo. You can follow these steps for doing initial commit.

1. Clone the empty repo.
   `git clone <your git repo url>`
2. Now go to your repo using `cd` command and create a local branch say `developement` using command
   `git checkout -b development`
3. We can now add some files in the repo `echo "A new repo" > Readme`
4. Stage all the unstages files to commit `git add .`
5. Show the staged files `git status`
6. Commit the files to local git repo `git commit -m "Adding readme file"`
7. Push the commit to your remote repo using `git push -u origin development:development`